# Query Database with Where Clause depending on array values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

You must have seen this in WordPress, how you pass arguments to function and it queries the database depending on the arguments you have passed. If the arguments are not passed. It will nautically fall back to the default arguments. Exactly same thing I want to do here in my custom function.

```
 function get_module( $args = NULL ){
    $defaults = array(
        "module_id" => NULL,
        "module_slug" => NULL,
        "module_parent" => NULL,
        "module_status" => "publish"
    );
    global $db;
    global $table_prefix;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_prefix" . "modules";
    $query = $db->SELECT($sql);
    return $db->FETCH_OBJECT();
}
```

Comment: And your question is how to do so? Well, what have you researched?

Comment: Google for "group_concat sql-server"

Comment: I have no idea what to search for. What I have tried is not efficient code has too many conditional tags. I don't want anyone to write me the whole code just explain what can be my next step. I can do it myself.

Comment: @Andomar thanks checking it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so lets do this step-by-step.

> If the arguments are not passed. It will nautically fall back to the default arguments

You already have a `$defaults` array, now the question is how to get it "together" with `$args` - the solution is using [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge). If you do merge `$args` and `$defaults`, you need to watch out that `$args`' elements override `$defaults` - not the other way round. ([fiddle](http://codepad.org/qBXO5VQK))

```
$options = array_merge($defaults, $args) // good
$options = array_merge($args, $defaults) // bad
```

Now the question is: Do you want to query the database for entries where the value is `NULL`? I don't think so, [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) comes in handy now to delete those elements not needed. This little snippet should already do the trick:

```
function notNull($value) {
    return $value !== NULL;
}
$options = array_filter($options, "notNull");
```

Now you have an array `$options` which should be used in the query. To do so you need to loop over the array, as you need both key and value for each item. While doing this you can already build your `WHERE` part.

```
$where = "";
if (count($options) > 0) {
    foreach ($options as $key=>$value) {
        if (!empty($where))
            $where .= " AND ";
        else
            $where = " WHERE ";

        $where .= sprintf("`%s` = `%s`", $key, $value);
    }
}
```

This will automatically convert values to string due to `sprintf()`, you can add additional checks (numeric values should not be quoted in MySQL I believe).

---

You could also use a prepared statement which will be created in the loop and set the values afterwards.

Comment: Awesomely explained. Thanks, works great and I have also learn't it.